# Double integral limit

Tags: calculus

Find this limit using double integral:
$$\lim_{m,n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac1{mn} \frac{\ell^2}{n^2} \sin \left( \frac{k\ell}{mn}\right)$$
$$m,n\in \mathbb{N}$$

I could use some help on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint
$$=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xy\cdot x^2\sin{(xy)}dxdy$$

Comment: Not sure about the term $xy$. Rather $= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^2sin(xy)dxdy$ as the limit of a Riemann-Lebesgue sum